# PHP: How to read XML file?

Tags: php, xml, function

I know read this XML file (example):

```
<product>
<id>1</id>
<name>Ferrari</name>
<info>The Car</info>
</product>
```

Im using this function for read this XML:

```
$request_url = "http://url-to-xml.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("error");

foreach($xml->product as $key) {
  $id   = $key->id;
  $name = $key->name;
```

in $id i have ID of product, in $name i have name of product..

**now my problem**

how to read this xml??

```
<product id="1" name="Ferrari">
 <info>
 The Car
 </info>
</product>
```

How to read this? `id=""`, `name=""` and `<info>`?

Comment: read http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php, and see http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php for how to get the data out. If you're using PHP, get in the habit of searching http://php.net first.

Comment: there is a full set of basic examples which guide you step-by-step in the PHP manual: http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic - also please search the site, this has been answered many many times.

Comment: I have errors with reading XML. I used the exmaple http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php and the print_r writting this: `SimpleXMLElement Object ( )` this is the xml: http://xml.itoffice.sk/Cenik2.xml why the script cant read it??

Comment: Stackoverflow is not meant to be a fix-service for your code. Please see the Help section how you can improve your questions.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
$id = $xml->product['id'];
$name = $xml->product['name'];
$info = $xml->product->info;
```